# Mark RPM as Automatically or Manually Installed

Tags: opensuse, rpm, dependencies, zypper

A question exists regarding [how to mark an RPM as automatically installed](https://serverfault.com/q/369451/50236), but that question concerns Fedora.

I am using `zypper` on OpenSUSE as an end-user and would like to know how to mark a package so that it will (or will not) show in the list of `unneeded` packages, with `zypper packages --unneeded`. I am looking for something along the lines of `zypper mark autoselected [packageName]`.

[A Novell Bugzilla bug](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=679213#c6) mentions a status of `byUser`, and possibly `autoselected`, so it sounds like this information exists somewhere. I would like to know how to modify it.

Comment: If RPM tools don't have a way to modify this information, but `zypper` does, I will modify the question title to specify OpenSUSE or `zypper`.

Comment: Tags help with the categorization.  The title, IMHO, is more about attracting the right people with the relevant knowledge about `zypper` and OpenSuse _as well as_ with `rpm`.  In the end, I would hazard to guess that the repository mappings are handled by `zypper`, just as `yum` does, rather than by `rpm`.  Additionally, the question that you linked in your own question shows that `yumdb` is used for this within Fedora, which would further support my assumption here.

Answer (score 2):

I would hazard to guess that the repository mappings are handled by `zypper`, just as `yum` does, rather than by `rpm`. Additionally, the question that you linked in your own question shows that `yumdb` is used for this purpose within Fedora, which would further support my assumption here.  The OpenSUSE [documentation](https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Standards_Rpm_Metadata#RPM_XML_Metadata) reveals:

> [RPM XML Metadata](http://createrepo.baseurl.org/wiki.html) format is mostly used for online repositories on the internet. It has its origins in the [YUM](http://yum.baseurl.org/) package manager.
>
> Just lately it was extended to support repositories split across multiple media.

See the source code for the OpenSUSE zypper schema specification [on github](https://github.com/openSUSE/libzypp/blob/master/zypp/parser/yum/schema/repomd.rng).  Although the metadata is part of the `rpm` package, it's either being used by `yum`/`zypper` (independently) or if the `rpm` tool *does* have that ability built-in, the database info is not shared between `yum` <--> `rpm` and/or `zypper` <--> `rpm`.

After reading the entirety of your question, I'm not sure if you're the end-user wishing to work with the zypperdb(?) or if you're a developer looking to build `rpm` packages.  For the latter, as I eluded to earlier, the information can be specified within an rpm `spec` file.

> ## rpm metadata
>
> This is an XML format for describing the critical metadata from an rpm
> package for dependency resolving and installation. Currently, this
> format is supported by apt-rpm,smartpm,red carpet and yum.
>
> The files break down as follows:
>
> - `repomd.xml` this is the file that describes the other metadata files. It
>   is like an index file to point to the other files. It
>   contains timestamps and checksums for the other files. This lets a
>   client download this one, small file and know if anything else has
>   changed. This also means that cryptographically (ex: gpg) signing this
>   one file can ensure repository integrity.
> - `primary.xml.[gz]` this file stores the primary metadata information. This
>   includes information such as:
>
>   - name, epoch, version, release, architecture
>   - file size, file location, description, summary, format, checksums
>     header byte-ranges, etc.
>   - dependencies, provides, conflicts, obsoletes, suggests, recommends
>   - file lists for the package for CERTAIN files - specifically files
>     matching: `/etc*`, `*bin/*`, `/usr/lib/sendmail` [1]
> - `filelists.xml.[gz]` this file stores the complete file and directory
>   listings for the packages. The package is identified by: name, epoch,
>   version, release, architecture and package checksum id.
> - `other.xml.[gz]` this file currently only stores the changelog data from
>   packages. However, this file could be used for any other
>   additional metadata that could be useful for clients.
> - `groups.xml.[gz]` this file is tentatively described. The intention is for
>   a common package-groups specification as well. There is still
>   some sections for this format that need to be fleshed out.
>
> **FIXME** The specification needs better and more current documentation
> and needs to be included here. :)

---

## Additional Resources

- [Zypper User Manual](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Zypper_usage)
- [Libzypp Repo Identification](https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Libzypp_repo_identifiaction)
- [Libzypp Features](https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Libzypp_features)
- [Libzypp Developer Documentation](https://doc.opensuse.org/projects/libzypp/HEAD/)

Comment: In this case, I am an end user wanting to work with the package database.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for similar option as with `apt-mark`, pattern here is little different.

To mark a package as automatically installed, add it to `/var/lib/zypp/AutoInstalled`.
To mark it as manually installed, remove it from there or reinstall with

```
zypper in -f <package-name>
```